# Laravel 5.2 Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to push my project to live server from local machine, where it is running fine. 
But when i pushed code to production machine and run following command:

```
composer update
```

it is showing me following error:

```
> > php artisan clear-compiled
> 
>                                    [BadMethodCallException]         Method after does not exist.  
>                                 
> 
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event
> returned with an error
> 
>                          [RuntimeException]     Error Output:       
>                       
> 
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
> [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers]
> [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies]
> [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
> [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
> [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs]
> [--] [<packages>]...
```

Please help! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only running 
`composer update`
won't help...

Try following the complete procedure [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

On the Production Server you should run only composer install! This should avoid your error. With update you install the newest configured version of each package required in your composer.json. With install you install the exact same version you used on your local server (stored in your composer.lock file).

Comment: I had a letter "W" randomly in my code that wouldn't let me run artisan at all, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's your `php artisan clear-compiled` command that is failing here. Most likely, the problem comes from when your application is booting. Somewhere, there is a call to the method `after` in your application, a method which does not exist. Please note that that call does not have be (and is indeed not) in the `ClearCompiledCommand`, but anywhere in your code.